# Exception on Gradle build

Tags: android, gradle, build, google-cardboard

I have cloned [this git](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk) and I tried to open sample projects using Android Studio.

After I opened any sample, it tried to build Gradle and it showed me build error. I looked at the logs and I found this exception.

```
org.gradle.tooling.BuildActionFailureException: The supplied build action failed with an exception.
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerConnection$CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableConsumerConnection.java:110)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:60)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:83)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:188)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:367)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:339)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:230)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:97)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:419)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:500)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:60)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.BuildControllerAdapter.getModel(BuildControllerAdapter.java:74)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.BuildControllerAdapter.getModel(BuildControllerAdapter.java:43)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:52)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:40)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this when I didn't import the entire cardboard SDK project and instead tried to just import one of the samples.

Answer (score 0):

I got to solve this by deleting the .idea folder from the root directory and then clean the project -> rebuild the project.
I solved my issue by this hack also